# A question about singular system

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

How can I define the formal power series ring $k[[x,y,z]]$, where $k$ is a field, in the Singular system?

Is it possible?

Comment: This is a question about how to use software. In a case like this, you should always prefer to use [the dedicated forum](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/forum/viewforum.php%3Ff=10&sid=dd1a5dbb19a5db1d7d4a4856f20bb791.html)